# OpportunityLineItems - why aren't they sent to trash can?

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

Question above.. Why not let the IsDeleted field apply to if the Opportunity Product is deleted from the parent Opp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Deleted-Opportunity-Line-Items/td-p/100775

I think this answers the question; it suggests that this is the default behaviour for master-detail relationships when the child is deleted, deleted records can apparently be found using the `getDeleted()` method.

Comment: Hey chowes, welcome to the site — this answer got a 'low quality' flag, primarily because you didn't provide any actual information. If you can expand your answers in future to be similar to my edit, you'll get a lot more upvotes :)